# Not able to render React Component to many times

Tags: reactjs

Why am I not able to render both components on the `#root`?

```js
ReactDOM.render(<Button text="Add"/>, window.root);
ReactDOM.render(<Button text="Delete"/>, window.root);
```

This only adds the second button to the `#root`

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const Button = ({ text, styleClass, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={e => onClick(e)}
      onToggle={e => onToggle(e)}
      className={'btn ${styleClass}'}
    >
      {text}
    </button>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<Button text="Add"/>, window.root);
ReactDOM.render(<Button text="Delete"/>, window.root);

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: because it overwrites the first one. You should either wrap both buttons using a div or Fragment and then render as one component or you should add them to different div's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why I am not able to render both components on the #root

Because the latter button overrode the former one.

---

In case you want to render two buttons, you might do this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const Button = ({ text, styleClass, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={e => onClick(e)}
      onToggle={e => onToggle(e)}
      className={'btn ${styleClass}'}
    >
      {text}
    </button>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
     <Button text="Add"/>
     <Button text="Delete"/>
  </div>,
  window.root  //or document.getElementById('root')
 ); 

<div id="root"></div>
```

---

A small working example

```js
const Button = ({text}) => <button>{text}</button>

ReactDOM.render(
   <div>
      <Button text='Add'/>
      <Button text='Delete'/>
   </div>,
   document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"><div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Because it basically shows the last component you are asking it to render.

Have a look at the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render

> `ReactDOM.render(element, container[, callback])` Render a React element
>   into the DOM in the supplied container and return a reference to the
>   component (or returns null for stateless components).
>
> If the React element was previously rendered into container, this will perform an
>   update on it and only mutate the DOM as necessary to reflect the
>   latest React element.

Answer (score 1):

The second one overrides the first dom rendered...

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <>
        <Button text="Add"/>
        <Button text="Add"/>
    <\>,
    window.root
);
```

This will render 2 buttons instead